# How can I find Membership type string for my local SQL Server 2008 

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am new to ASP.NET and C#.

I am trying to connect a SQL Server database (its local) to a form for the first time.

I was able to find out connection string through server explorer but I can not find
Membership type string..

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />

        <add name="sqlProvider" type="??"/>
```

How can I find out the membership type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, it is in docs [Configuring an ASP.NET Application to Use Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e9y4s5t.aspx).

As you can see, membership is based on provider model, so you can extend it with your own provider. .NET ships with providers defined in [System.Web.Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The type for a membership provider should be `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`.  Below I have put a typical `<membership />` block for reference.

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="yourConnStringName"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="50"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         applicationName="yourApplicationName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put connection string and membership block which should be laid in web.config.

#### see below snippest.

```
<configuration>
```

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="8"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="50"
         minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
         requiresUniqueEmail="true"
         enablePasswordReset="true"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
         applicationName="yourApplicationName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Change connection string as per your requirement in above block of code.